# observe_form url confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, observer-pattern

i cannot seem to get observe_form to call a particular action

i have a route defined

```
map.resources :charges, :collection => {:charge_total => :get}
```

my controller

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def charge_total
    return 'foo'
  end
end
```

my view: i have tried both...

```
observe_form form_id, :update => :charge_total, :url => :charge_total_charges
```

and

```
observe_form form_id, :update => :charge_total, :url => {:controller => :charges, :action => :charge_total}
```

when the form updates, i get an unknown action error

```
No action responded to update. Actions: charge_total, create
```

it sees that there is an action charge_total, however it is trying to respond to update?  im not sure what is going on. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bahh!
put, not get...

map.resources :charges, :collection => {:charge_total => :put}